# finding $resource objects in array and skip push if exists / angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, resources, promise, deferred

I'm breaking my head on this one.

From my backend I fetch json data for my typeahead input field.
once a value is selected I fetch the full object from the backend by using the unique id that came with the auto complete response.

next thing i do is to push this object into an array and then i itterate over this array to display in the html all fine.

but i would like to test first if the object is already in the array.
for that i'm using array.indexOf property, however for some reason it will never find a match: i hope someone can help me:

here is the code:

the factory:

```
  productServices.factory('Product', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
       return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/products/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
            query: {  method:'GET', 

            isArray:false,

            responseType:'json',

            cache:true},

  update: { method:'PUT' }
```

fetch product from backend and push to an array:

```
   $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
  $scope.$item = $item

   // call the .addProduct service to push the product.get result into a list
  acProductService.addProduct(Product.get({ id: $scope.$item.id }));

  // this is to retrieve the list
  $scope.products = acProductService.getProducts();


  // reset field
  $scope.selected = '';

   };
```

service to push the data to the array and to list the array (so here on addProduct i would like to test if the object is already in the array)

```
 autocompServices.service('acProductService', function() {
 var productList = [];

 var addProduct = function(newObj) {
    console.log(productList.indexOf(newObj));  ---- here is my issue it will          never find the newObj despite i've added it many times
    productList.push(newObj);    
    console.log(productList.indexOf(newObj)); -- does work but i need to check before pushing to the list and not after;
  };

  var getProducts = function(){
  return productList;
   };

 return {
    addProduct: addProduct,
    getProducts: getProducts
 };
```

i'm guessing the $resource.get returns something that is unique irrespective of the object retrieved from the back-end is actually unique. any help please.. thanks

Comment: if you console log productList the second time you try to add the same object, do you actually see it in your array?

Comment: yes it does show up, the thing works but i want to avoid duplicates and instead add a qty field

Comment: if its in there and its not finding it, maybe use a for loop with angular.equals which compare all properties of your objects

Comment: thanks, but also this one doesn't match. looks like i'm comparing different types of data. one is the object stored in the array and the other is the response returned from the $resource.get

Comment: got it working now by using the angular.equals function (to avoid the $$haskey being part of the object for comparing) - thanks atsituab for the direction.  then also needed to add an interceptor to the resource function in order to modify the response with angular.fromJson